# AHK GUI issue - edit variables not pulling through

Tags: user-interface, autohotkey

I have made a script GUI for AHk which has several input boxes.
The problem comes when I try to enter information and click OK it does not seem to save/assign this info to each variable I have set in the code.

Here is the code:

```
Gui, Add, Text, x20 y10 w120 h20, Date:
Gui, Add, Edit, x80 y10 w120 h20 vDate,
Gui, Add, Text, x20 y40 w120 h20, Time:
Gui, Add, Edit, x80 y40 w120 h20 vTime

;Material 1
Gui, Add, Text, x20 y70 w120 h20, Material 1:
Gui, Add, Edit, x80 y70 w120 h20 vMaterial1
Gui, Add, Text, x217 y70 w120 h20, Quantity:
Gui, Add, Edit, x267 y70 w80 h20 vQuantity1
Gui, Add, Text, x367 y70 w120 h20, Unit of measure:
Gui, Add, Edit, x453 y70 w60 h20 vUnit1

;Material 2
Gui, Add, Text, x20 y100 w120 h20, Material 2:
Gui, Add, Edit, x80 y100 w120 h20 vMaterial2
Gui, Add, Text, x217 y100 w120 h20, Quantity:
Gui, Add, Edit, x267 y100 w80 h20 vQuantity2
Gui, Add, Text, x367 y100 w120 h20, Unit of measure:
Gui, Add, Edit, x453 y100 w60 h20 vUnit2

;Material 3
Gui, Add, Text, x20 y130 w120 h20, Material 3:
Gui, Add, Edit, x80 y130 w120 h20 vMaterial3
Gui, Add, Text, x217 y130 w120 h20, Quantity:
Gui, Add, Edit, x267 y130 w80 h20 vQuantity3
Gui, Add, Text, x367 y130 w120 h20, Unit of measure:
Gui, Add, Edit, x453 y130 w60 h20 vUnit3

;Material 4
Gui, Add, Text, x20 y160 w120 h20, Material 4:
Gui, Add, Edit, x80 y160 w120 h20 vMaterial4
Gui, Add, Text, x217 y160 w120 h20, Quantity:
Gui, Add, Edit, x267 y160 w80 h20 vQuantity4
Gui, Add, Text, x367 y160 w120 h20, Unit of measure:
Gui, Add, Edit, x453 y160 w60 h20 vUnit4

;Material 5
Gui, Add, Text, x20 y190 w120 h20, Material 5:
Gui, Add, Edit, x80 y190 w120 h20 vMaterial5,
Gui, Add, Text, x217 y190 w120 h20, Quantity:
Gui, Add, Edit, x267 y190 w80 h20 vQuantity5,
Gui, Add, Text, x367 y190 w120 h20, Unit of measure:
Gui, Add, Edit, x453 y190 w60 h20 vUnit5

Gui, Add, Button, x80 y240 w70 h20, OK
Gui, Add, Button, x167 y240 w70 h20, Cancel
Gui, Show, x100 y100 h270 w550
Return
ButtonCancel:
GuiClose:
ExitApp

ButtonOk:
Gui, submit, Nohide

;test ----
MsgBox unit material 4 - %vUnit4%

ExitApp
```

I tried re-arranging the variable names with no results.
I have a message box after the script is done as a check during development to check if the variables were captured but it doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `v`.
Use `%Unit4%` instead of `%vUnit4%` if you want to do stuff with the variable.
Value entered via UI will be correctly displayed:

```
MsgBox unit material 4 - %Unit4%
```

Of course keep `v` here:

```
Gui, Add, Edit, x453 y160 w60 h20 vUnit4
```

More info on variables are in documentation (have a look at V:Variable section)
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#Events